# Ticker not working on selected pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ticker

My website is [www.codtelevision.com](http://www.codtelevision.com).

If you look at the home page, it is perfect, but when you go to another page, it is big and looks weird. How do I fix it, and what is wrong? Thanks! If you need some code, I will be glad to post some, or you can view it on my site.

I just looked at chrome developer tools, and found this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have jQuery included after your jQuery code on your other pages (it needs to be included before). So you end up with just a block of code that isn't functioning as a ticker. Put the call before it and you'll be good.

Comment: i'll believe you because of 14k rep, but i did not know that

Comment: @ScottSelby - didn't know what?

Comment: I just mis-understood the problem

Comment: @ScottSelby -understood. Basically the ticker code is just an unordered list of items and the jQuery should be modifying the display of that. Since the code is being called prior to jQuery being loaded it's failing and remaining as a regular unordered list.

Comment: yup - I was trying to answer too fast

Comment: i think your answer is correct, i am trying it out, and adding it to each page..the top

Comment: @EliteGamer - Seems to be working now and I see no error in the console other than an intermittent google ads issue. Did my suggestion help?

Answer (score 0):

its because the ticker expands the height as more content gets added and everything is positioned absolute, you need to position something other then absolute, maybe relative , or arrange the elements so they have room to expand

Comment: then why does it work on the home page and does not on the other pages...Also, it has been working until i had my Nivo slider fixed...

Comment: oh, I might not be getting the problem, it works fine on my browser, just it expands under another element

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget add `ticker-active` class to your other pages. And make sure you call the initialize javascript function.